# WebUI.maximizeWindow() not working for Katalon Docker image?

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, katalon-studio

WebUI.maximizeWindow() does not work for katalon docker image,

The command works fine on Katalon desktop, but when I run this on docker image it seems to ignore the command completely.

```
WebUI.openBrowser(GlobalVariable.url, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
WebUI.maximizeWindow(FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)
```

The window should be maximized after using that command!